# Export from mongodb with converted object id to string

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I want to export from mongodb where objectId will be converted to string when exporting.

```
ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").toString()
```

This does not work with export command. I tried the following but that showing syntax error.

```
./mongoexport --host localhost --db Database --collection collection_name --type=csv --out collection.csv --fields _id.toString()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with a single command, but after running your export, you can use `sed` to convert to a string.

```
sed -i 's/ObjectId(\([[:alnum:]]*\))/\1/g' collection.csv
```

I got [the pattern from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60110512/sed-replace-fixed-text-and-parenthesis-from-string).

Answer (score 0):

mongoexport won't do what you want because of moongoimport - these tools are used for exporting/importing a database and they use only one format. You should be trying to use mongodump or mongorestore.

Comment: mongodump and mongorestore use binary format isn't it? Are you saying it is impossible to do this with mongoexport?