# sed -> replace fixed text and parenthesis from string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How to bring this expression

```
echo "ObjectId(5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780),'qwe',ObjectId(5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780),()"
```

to this

```
5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780,'qwe',5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780,()
```

using `sed`?

I use this:

```
echo "ObjectId(5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780),'qwe',ObjectId(5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780),()" | \
   sed 's/ObjectId(\([a-z0-9]\)/\1/'
```

Comment: You say expected is `5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780,'qwe',5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780,()`, but then you say "I cannot delete the final bracket". Please confirm what exact output you need.

Comment: Have you tried using a regex tester like https://regex101.com/ to see if your regular expression is correct?

Comment: @Bart regex101 should be used with caution when testing out patterns that should be POSIX BRE compliant, as the tool is only for PCRE, JS, Python `re` and Golang regex flavors. One should be aware how to "convert" the pattern later and what constructs to avoid.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point! radya100 Please match your particular regex flavour when using a test tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/ObjectId(\([[:alnum:]]*\))/\1/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/vM9qjr)

The POSIX BRE pattern means:

- `ObjectId(` - matches a literal string
- `\([[:alnum:]]*\)` - Group 1: zero or more alphanumeric chars
- `)` - a literal `)`.

The `\1` replacement will keep the Group 1 value only.

The `g` flag will replace all occurrences.

Comment: Output is as expected, `5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780,'qwe',5e257e424ed10b0015e3e780,()`. Why does someone think this solution is wrong?

Comment: @radya100 Ok, I fixed the question formatting and removed the confusing part.

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/ObjectId(\([^)]*\))/\1/g' file` ?

Comment: @potong Sure, but in the question, the requirements for the part between parentheses are not specified.